# query mysql database with pandas selectively

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Is there a way to query a mysql table using pandas only when there is an UPDATE or INSERT operation on the corresponding table? I couldn't find a relevant argument in pandas read_sql. I need to query a table frequently so want to avoid pulling the data if there was no update/insert.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this mean: *when there is an UPDATE or INSERT operation on the corresponding table*? How can an SQL statement be on a table?

Comment: @Parfait: an e.g. query is 'select * from <table_name>'. Using pandas, I want to run this query but only when the records of <table_name> table are either updated or a new record is inserted.

Comment: Python pandas and MySQL are two different, unconnected data stores. Neither of them know what is considered *updated* or *new* records. In fact, within MySQL you wouldn't know this status type. Only you the user would know. You could maintain in db table, timestamps of *created* and *modified* and check against last time you ran pandas.